# Lipschitz constant of $\log(1 + \exp(\lvert x \rvert ))$

Tags: derivatives, continuity, lipschitz-functions, logistic-regression

Following the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#Properties) we have that "An everywhere differentiable function $g : \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz continuous (with $K = \sup \lvert g'(x)\rvert$) if and only if it has bounded first derivative."

Hence, the Lipschitz constant of $\log(1+ \exp(-x))$ equals $1$ since its derivative is bounded in $(-1,0)$.

I was wondering whether the same result can be applied for $\log(1+ \exp(\lvert x\rvert))$. The analysis would be mostly the same, but the condition "everywhere differentiable" does not hold anymore.

Comment: Yes: the same result holds for functions which are weakly differentiable (or absolutely continuous) with bounded weak derivative, such as $\log (1+ e^{|x|})$.

Comment: @Crostul thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x) = \log\left(1 + \exp(|x|\right)$,

- if $x > 0$ and $y < 0$:

$$\left|g(x) - g(y)\right| \le |g(x)| + |g(y)| \le |x| + |y| = |x - y|$$

This is the only problematic case. Other cases can be handled easily.